Proving a conclusion from pigeonhole principle
I learned about the (simple version) of the pigenhole principle, i.e.
For n>k, if one distributes n pigeons  among k pigenholes, then at least one pigenhole contains two pigens.
To write it more formally:
Suppose $n>k$. Let $f:\{1,...,n\}$ $\rightarrow \{1,...,k\}$ be a map and then there exists $m \in \{1,...,k\}$ such that $f^{-1}(\{m\})$ contains at least two elements, i.e. $|f^{-1}(\{m\})|\geq 2$.
Now I want to prove the (better) following version:
Suppose $n>k$. Let $f:\{1,...,n\}$ $\rightarrow \{1,...,k\}$ be a map and then there exists $m \in \{1,...,k\}$ such that $|f^{-1}(\{m\})|\geq \lfloor{\frac{n-1}{k}}\rfloor+1$.
My thoughts:
I do understand the statement and I understand why it is true. But I don't know how to (formally) argue here.
The statement is true, because let $n>k$.
Then there exists $a,r \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n=ak+r$.
Then one can map $a$ elements of $\{1,...,n\}$ to some element $i \in$ $\{1,...,k\}$.
Thus we are left with $r$ "unused" elements in \${1,...,n}$, where k>r.
This means there has to be one element $j$ in $\{1,...,k\}$ such that $|f^{-1}(\{j\})| \geq a+1$.
But I do not know why $a$ has to equal $\lfloor{\frac{n-1}{k}}\rfloor$.
Why is that so?
Further, is there a "more elegant" way to prove this statement (or to write the same idea more elegently).

The usual way would be by contradiction. Assume that for all $m$ the number is $\le \lfloor \frac{n-1}{k}\rfloor$. Also, $\lfloor \frac{n-1}{k}\rfloor+1 = \lceil  \frac{n}{k}\rceil$

Proof by contradiction: if all $\left| f^{-1}(m)\right| \le \lfloor\frac{n-1}{k} \rfloor \le \frac{n-1}{k}$, then
$$ n = \left | \bigcup_{m=1}^n f^{-1}(m) \right| = \sum_{m=1}^n \left| f^{-1}(m)\right| \le n-1$$
Contradiction!
